# Javascript. Restrict the user to input the same number characters as in the textbox

Tags: javascript

I will flash a scrambled word and then the user will type in what the scrambled word is.

So far I have this code. This is for shuffle and display.

```
document.getElementById("shuffle").value = shuffle(document.getElementById("word").value);
var shuffledword = document.getElementById("shuffle").value;
var z = shuffledword.split("").join('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML=z;

var str=document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
var n=str.replace(charcode,"...");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=n;
```

What I want is to restrict the user to input the same number letters as in the shuffled word. Example: the word is "DOOMED"; I want to make it so that the user cannot click the letter D and O three times, but only once or twice. Same for the other letters, depending on the number letters in the shuffled word.

It this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Set an object with each letters of the (shuffled) word and their count
var letters = {};
for (var i=0 ; i<word.length ; i++) {
  var c = word.charAt(i);
  if ( ! letters[c]) letters[c] = 1;
  else letters[c]++;
}

...

function process_user_char(K) {
  // When user enter letter K
  if ( ! letters[K]) {
    alert("You cannot enter " + K);
    return false;
  }
  else {
    letters[K]-- ;
    return true;
  }
}

....

// To check wether user entered all letters, returns Yes or No
function check_if_user_entered_all_letters() {
  for (var o in letters) {
    if (letters[o]) return "No";
  }
  return "Yes";
}
```

*edit* Added `return true / false` in process_user_char to integrate into *onkeypressed*.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HQXwY/).